# how to replace substring of html contents in PHP, but not inside url or href?

Tags: php, substring, href, str-replace

i'm trying to replace substring like below

```
products of cctv <a href="cctv.jpg"> new cctv</a> of cctv ...
```

so when replace must be **cctv** with **tablets** must become like this

```
products of tablets <a href="cctv.jpg"> new tablets</a> of tablets ...
```

is the function or solution , because str_replace function replace every where.

Comment: use preg_replace() or $string = str_replace('new cctv','new  tablets',$str);

Comment: If the only place this bothers you is cctv.jpg, you can replace cctv.jpg first with %placeholder%%, then you replace cctv with tablets, and then replace %placeholder%% with cctv.jpg again. Not elegant but it works.

Comment: You can use `.text()`. For Eg: `$('a').text("new tablets")`;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$str = 'products of cctv <a href="cctv.jpg"> new cctv</a> of cctv ';
$parts = preg_split('/(<(?:[^"\'>]|"[^"<]*"|\'[^\'<]*\')*>)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
for ($i=0, $n=count($parts); $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    $parts[$i] = preg_replace("/(cctv)/", "tablets", $parts[$i]);
}
$str = implode('', $parts);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Not what the asker is looking for.

Comment: this function replace evry substring even in href , and i need to keep the url the same , thank u for reply

Comment: Yeah ... did not know that. Will be helpful answer if any found. +1 vote for your question.

Comment: Hey please check my updated answer...its working.
Did googling for sometime and got that

Comment: i will check update answer now, i google it for two days and did not got good answers.